# Deserialize string not converting array

Tags: c#, json.net, javascriptserializer

I have this string that I am trying to deserialize to an object, but every time it is converted the Roles Property is not converted back.

{"LoginAttemptId":235,"UserProfileId":4,"Username":"devclient1","Id":null,"SubscriptionType":null,"Roles":["Client"]}

I have tried both these Deserialization methods:

```
PauperToPresidentSerializedModel serializeModel = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PauperToPresidentSerializedModel>(decUserData);

                //PauperToPresidentSerializedModel serializeModel
                //    = serializer.Deserialize<PauperToPresidentSerializedModel>(decUserData);
```

and both give me and object where the Roles property is Null, instead of having 'Client' in it.

here is the PauperToPresidentSerializedModel obejct definition

```
public class PauperToPresidentSerializedModel
    {
        public long LoginAttemptId { get; set; }

        public long UserProfileId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string SubscriptionType { get; set; }
        public string[] Roles { get; private set; }
        public PauperToPresidentSerializedModel(PauperToPresidentPrincipal principal)
        {
            LoginAttemptId = principal.LoginAttemptId;
            UserProfileId = principal.UserProfileId;
            Username = principal.Username;
            Id = principal.Id;
            SubscriptionType = principal.SubscriptionType;
            Roles = principal.Roles;
        }
        public PauperToPresidentSerializedModel()
        {            
        }
    }
```

Comment: missing PauperToPresidentSerializedModel definition, please edit your question

Comment: Your setter for Roles is private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Roles` field has a **private** setter. You could:

1. Make it public
2. Have the contract resolver access private fields:

   `contractResolver.DefaultMembersSearchFlags |= BindingFlags.NonPublic;`
3. Create a custom contract resolver (I am guessing you don't want to go that route).

Comment: Thanks I totally missed the private setter

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the properties public in order to serialize and deserialize:

```
public string[] Roles { get; set; }
```